# ClearContents deleting data out of range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to have this piece of code clear the contents of a certain range, before I bring new data. This range has a header right in the above row, which is getting cleared as well, although the range doesn't include it.

I've tried specifying the range and having other cells selected before running it, but the header gets cleared anyway.

```
With MyResults
    LastRowResults = Range("A16:K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A$16:$K$" & LastRowResults).Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
```

It's clearing row 15 and even the content of cell A9, some of the times I run it.

The goal is to have this range cleared, keeping formulas in some columns intact, so that filtered data down the road can be brought in, making up the report required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoiding `Select` and `Activate` in VBA does miracles in performance and coding abilities ([How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)). Concerning your code, try to avoid the header, if it is a default at line 16:

```
With MyResults
    LastRowResults = .Range("A17:K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    MsgBox LastRowResults 'Consider removing this line, once the code works.
    Dim deleteArea As Range
    Set deleteArea = .Range("A$17:$K$" & LastRowResults)
    deleteArea.ClearContents
End With
```

In the OP code, there was a lack of `.` before the `Range` in this line:

```
LastRowResults = .Range("A17:K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Thus, the `lastRowResults` was getting its value from the `ActiveSheet` or the Sheet in which the code resides (if not in a module). The `.` is quite important in the `With MyResult`.

In general, when the last row is searched for multiple columns, then one should define exactly the expected output. E.g., the for the biggest last row, something like this is way better:

```
LastRowResults = .Columns("A:K").Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
```

Comment: Does this prevent `.End(xlUp)` from making the range "negative" if the last filled cell in column A was, say, row 9?

Comment: I'm thinking that that's causing OPs frustration

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 - now, when I think about it, you probably have a point.

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 - but I guess, the lack of `.` before the `Range` for the `lastRowResults` is the general reason - it takes the last row of another worksheet and thus it causes the "negative range".

Comment: Hi @Vityata! Thanks for the prompt response. It keeps clearing from A9 downwards with the code below:
 With MyResults
        LastRowResults = .Range("A17:K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        'MsBox LastRowResults 'Commented this, as it gave me an error, saying that there's a sub or function missing.
        Set deleteArea = .Range("A$17:$K$" & LastRowResults)
        deleteArea.ClearContents 'It deleted all formulas, but they need to be kept. 
    End With
Any idea as a workaround?
Again: Thanks!

Comment: @AntonioSantos - The MsgBox is simply a Message box. Try to make it and see the value of the `LastRowResults` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/msgbox-function

Comment: The result is: 6, @Vityata! ...and every time I run it, this number decreases, deleting data upwards.

Comment: @AntonioSantos - did you put the "DOT" - `.` before the word Range? Exactly as in my code? Like `.Range("A17:K")`?

Comment: Yes, I did, @Vityata!

Comment: @AntonioSantos - can you delete all the other worksheets, except for the `MyResults` and try again?

Comment: @Vityata, I keep getting the same result, where it deletes everything and goes upwards, everytime I run it.

Comment: @AntonioSantos - you deleted all the other sheets in the Excel file and now you have only one sheet left?

Comment: Correct, @Vityata!

Comment: @AntonioSantos - try this `LastRowResults = .Columns("A:K").Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row` instead of `LastRowResults = .Range("A17:K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: It still deletes rows' contents above - unfortunately. I'll try another approach later today and will let you how this unfolds.

Comment: Hello @Vityata, 
Would that be the case to use .End(xlDown) instead?
Anyway, I ended up setting a range whose contents are to be cleared and it suffices for now. Thanks a lot for getting involved!